# Loop through an array of JSON object while putting statistic data dynamically in a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to output statistic data in a table dynamically in JavaScript from a API which contains an array of JSON object, where in the JSON data, the property score is interpreted like this:

> score: 5 (excellent);
>
> score: 4 (very good);
>
> score: 3 (Reasonable);
>
> score: 2 (bad);
>
> score: 1 (horrible);

Now, the challenge is: while looping in the array, add statistic data in the table.
 The statistic data should be calculate based on the `shop name` and its `score`. for example, in the JSON, we have 2 shop in the property `(storeName)` for the same company in different location and the owner wanna evaluate each performance separately based on the customers' feedback.

In the array for the property and value `"storeName": "Dito Savassi"`, we have 4 occurrences for this shop (the calculus should be like this :

> totalOfExcellence/totalOccurencesOfThisShop*100 (2/4*100),
>   totalOfVeryGood /totalOccurencesOfThisShop*100; totalOfVeryGood
>   /totalOccurencesOfThisShop*100;and so on).

After you'll repeat the process for the `"storeName": "Dito Rio de Janeiro"`, which has one row (1 occurence) and a `totalOfVeryGood = 1;`
the column `"satisfaction"` in the table is made: `(totalOfExcellence + totalOfVeryGood );` and the column `"Evaluation"` in the table is `the number of occurence of each shop or total row for each shop`.

I already made the report for all shop together, now this case I don't know how to make it work. Do anyone have any idea?

```js
[{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2018-09-01T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2018-09-01T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 2,
    "storeName": "Dito Rio de Janeiro",
    "score": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2018-09-02T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2018-09-3T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2018-09-03T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 2
  }
]
```

The result should be like this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name of the shop</th>
      <th>Satisfaction</th>
      <th>Evaluation</th>
      <th>excellent</th>
      <th>Very Good</th>
      <th>Reasonable</th>
      <th>Bad</th>
      <th>horribel</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 Dito Savassi</td>
      <td>50%</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>50%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 Dito Rio de Janeiro</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0%</td>
      <td>100%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
      <td>0%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so, what you tried to achieve the expected output?

Comment: I put the Html table that should be the final answer of my question...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2018-09-01T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2018-09-01T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 2,
    "storeName": "Dito Rio de Janeiro",
    "score": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2018-09-02T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2018-09-3T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2018-09-03T13:27:57.334Z",
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Dito Savassi",
    "score": 2
  }
];
var tr_data = '';
for (var key in jsonData) {
  //console.log(jsonData[key]); 
  if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(jsonData[key].storeName);
    var review = '';
    switch (jsonData[key].score) {
      case 1:
        review = 'horrible';
        break;
      case 2:
        review = 'bad';
        break;
      case 3:
        review = 'Reasonable';
        break;
      case 4:
        review = 'very good';
        break;
      case 5:
        review = 'excellent';
        break;
    }
    tr_data += '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + jsonData[key].id + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + jsonData[key].date + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + jsonData[key].storeId + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + jsonData[key].storeName + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + jsonData[key].score + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + review + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  }
}

var htmlTable = '<table cellpadding="10" style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;background-color: #EEEEEE;width: 100%;text-align: left;">' +
  '<thead>' +
  '<tr>' +
  '<th>Id</th>' +
  '<th>Date</th>' +
  '<th>Store Id</th>' +
  '<th>Store Name</th>' +
  '<th>Score</th>' +
  '<th>Review</th>' +
  ' </tr>' +
  '</thead>' +
  ' <tbody>' + tr_data + '</tbody>' +
  '</table>';
document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = htmlTable;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resultDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Zeshan...i mean you made the table dynamic which i want too. but the data that i want to output in table is missing.  you can ask me for clarify more my question or take a deeper look in it to undertand better what i wanna output. the result should be like the Html table i put in the question with those statistic values.